# Go Buffalo: ERRO[0000] Error: name buffalodevn is not allowed, try a different application name

Tags: go, buffalo

When trying to start a new buffalo project in my Go Path I get this error, in my search I don't see any references to this error in the docs or in other questions on different forums. I've tried different names in different forms but I always get the same error and I can't figure out why. (tried names without buffalo)

```
ERRO[0000] Error: name buffalodevn is not allowed, try a different application name
```

when I run Buffalo Info

```
-> Go: Checking installation
✓ The `go` executable was found on your system at: /usr/local/go/bin/go

-> Go: Checking minimum version requirements
✓ Your version of Go, 1.13.4, meets the minimum requirements.

-> Go: Checking GOPATH
✓ You are using Go Modules, so no need to worry about the GOPATH.

-> Go: Checking Package Management
✓ You are using Go Modules (`go`) for package management.

-> Go: Checking PATH
✓ Your PATH contains /home/alexmerced/go/bin.

-> Node: Checking installation
✓ The `node` executable was found on your system at: /usr/bin/node

-> Node: Checking minimum version requirements
✓ Your version of Node, v12.13.1, meets the minimum requirements.

-> NPM: Checking installation
✓ The `npm` executable was found on your system at: /usr/bin/npm

-> NPM: Checking minimum version requirements
✓ Your version of NPM, 6.13.4, meets the minimum requirements.

-> Yarn: Checking installation
✘ The `yarnpkg` executable could not be found on your system.
For help setting up your Yarn environment please follow the instructions for you platform at:

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

-> PostgreSQL: Checking installation
✘ The `postgres` executable could not be found on your system.
For help setting up your Postgres environment please follow the instructions for you platform at:

https://www.postgresql.org/download/

-> MySQL: Checking installation
✘ The `mysql` executable could not be found on your system.
For help setting up your MySQL environment please follow the instructions for you platform at:

https://www.mysql.com/downloads/

-> SQLite3: Checking installation
✓ The `sqlite3` executable was found on your system at: /usr/bin/sqlite3

-> SQLite3: Checking minimum version requirements
✓ Your version of SQLite3, 3.29.0, meets the minimum requirements.

-> Cockroach: Checking installation
✘ The `cockroach` executable could not be found on your system.
For help setting up your Cockroach environment please follow the instructions for you platform at:

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/

-> Buffalo (CLI): Checking installation
✓ The `buffalo` executable was found on your system at: /usr/local/bin/buffalo

-> Buffalo (CLI): Checking minimum version requirements
✓ Your version of Buffalo (CLI), v0.15.3, meets the minimum requirements.

-> Buffalo: Application Details
Pwd         /home/alexmerced
Root        /home/alexmerced
GoPath      /home/alexmerced/go
PackagePkg  alexmerced
ActionsPkg  alexmerced/actions
ModelsPkg   alexmerced/models
GriftsPkg   alexmerced/grifts
WithModules true
Name        alexmerced
Bin         bin/alexmerced
VCS         
WithPop     false
WithSQLite  false
WithDep     false
WithWebpack false
WithNodeJs  false
WithYarn    false
WithDocker  false
WithGrifts  false
AsWeb       true
AsAPI       false
InApp       false
PackageJSON {map[]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question since I had the same problem and searched for a solution... Then I had a look into the source and found:

```
fb := append(opts.ForbiddenNames, "buffalo", "test", "dev")
```

So it seems the name is not allowed to contain "buffalo", "test" or "dev".

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue and it's weird but it looks like you can't create project "test_project" 

Comment: Yes, my failed try was test_site ... (-: And I was not able to find the info in the net, only the source offered the answer.

Comment: This is so stupid. I want to create a project with name `developer_console` which is not allowed.

Comment: Hey , This one should have been fixed in v0.16.11. Thanks for pointing it out. This might have been residual technical debt from one of our original CLI's implementation.